# Xubuntu-possible to change the icons of the application indicators separately?

Tags: xubuntu, icons, indicator

I was wondering if it is possible to change how to icons look in the top panel (application indicators?) separately. I am in love with the Numix Circle icon package, but unfortunately, its application indicators are not the best. I'd rather use the default icon set in my top panel.

Is it possible to change those icons separately from the icon pack I am currently using? I would like to have elementary Xfce dark icons on my top panel.

Thank a lot in advance

Comment: It seems to be not really easy... Numix-Circle saves his icons in `/usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle` but it inherits icons from the Numix icon-theme. If you wanna change an icon it could be also in the Numix folder. You can copy both to `$HOME/.icons` rename the folders and the names in the index.theme files, so its possible to experiment with the icon-themes and not damage the original icon-themes.